# Pack all pictures into single archive on server and unpack on client-side

Tags: http, archive

So, is it possible to create archive (/binary array?) ones on server side and then send it + run-time generated HTML page. I think it is. And wondering if there's any libraries for that. Client side especially.

Core questions now are:
1. How to transfer image: as a js variable? Like `var imagebinary = "3nmrnmfu5...."`
2. How to turn image back from binary format and paste them where necessarily.

Now I'm thinking of using data: URL.

**tomfumb** suggested a brilliant solution that google uses: one "big" image that got caught into smaller pieces on client.

Comment: Yes - as it is done, for example, in Opera mht files.

Comment: but what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: There's web server (node.js if necessarily). Pages has lots of pictures on them, so each picture would be queried separately. It the best case - I would use keep-alive, but will have to make more disk queries and anyway, it seems to me that one bigger answer will be better for server than lot's of small query-answers, am I right?

Comment: I've never looked at it before but I don't think a web browser would know what to do with such a response from a server, and would just download it to the file system. I think you're better off looking at caching and compression strategies for your content to reduce unique requests from clients. Look at how Google and Facebook handles high volumes of traffic (besides enormous server farms). Go with the standard but make it as efficient as you can. For static plain text content use gzip / deflate and tell clients to cache where appropriate. Use Fiddler to see how your browser uses popular sites

Comment: I meant send it as a part of simple page - in invisible div for example (or even as js variable) - and than unpack using javascript. And сaching, of course. The core question now for me is - how to make such chain of transformation: image -> binary -> image (and place it where necessarily using js).

Comment: you can't send a binary as part of a web page (in a div, js variable, or anywhere else), it has to be referenced (e.g. in the 'src' attribute of an image) to tell the browser to go and download it. The browser would then handle it as it would any other archive - by downloading it. What you're talking about is incompatible with the way web pages work. Again, I suggest you study how very successful companies do this sort of thing; don't try and reinvent the wheel (or, in your case, don't try to invent a new kind of wheel). You might be able to use flash player or something to unpack ....

Comment: .... your archive, then have it pass javascript commands to the browser to render the unpacked HTML, but this seems like waaaaaaaaaaay more effort than it's worth. I would also question if you're even going to see the level of traffic you're trying to avoid here

Comment: @MInner let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2451/discussion-between-tomfumb-and-minner)

Comment: For those who would look o this page in the future: now it seems like data;uri is a good way of dealing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the technique you're looking for often gets called "CSS Sprites", and there are quite a few good articles on them around the place (just ask your favourite search engine). There are other methods using Javascript instead, but I quite like the CSS method myself.

There are quite a good articles at:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

and many others.

The idea is to combine all the images into one larger image, then use CSS to control which parts of the larger image to display in any particular case.

Say you have four identical sized images, 1,2,3,4   (they don't have to be identical size but
it makes the explanation easier

Combine them into one larger image using your favourite server side image toolkit. Something like GD from PHP, or ImageMagick, or PIL if you're using Python. Most server side kits have a library that can combine images.

1234

Then create CSS rules that will display the relevant part of the bigger image on the client:

for example:

```
div.sprite {  height:100px; width:100px;  }
#image1 {  background: url(bigimg.png) 0 0; }
#image2 {  background: url(bigimg.png) -100px 0; width: 100px;}
#image3 {  background: url(bigimg.png) -200px 0; width: 100px;}
#image4 {  background: url(bigimg.png) -300px 0; width: 100px;}
```

and the HTML to display them:

```
<div id='image1' class='sprite'></div> 
<div id='image2' class='sprite'></div> 
<div id='image3' class='sprite'></div> 
<div id='image4' class='sprite'></div>
```

It's the kind of thing it probably isn't too difficult to automate.

Comment: Yes. That seem to be exactly what I meant. Thank you.